# Minimum setup for web services in IIS?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, web-services, iis, asp.net-web-api

I've been involved in a project using SAPUI5 recently. My web background so far has mainly been developing ASP MVC apps but I've never really bothered to go very deep, to understand how ASP apps are being set up behind the scenes.

Recently, I've seen a need for the client side (JavaScript) code to query the local IIS for various system-related information, such as the Windows user ID etc. So, I thought a web service would be the natural approach.

However, since the web site isn't set up to handle ASP web services I can't make that work out of the box. Just adding a web service to the web site automatically creates an "App_Code" folder to host the C# implementation files but when the client calls a service it just gets a 404 back, so I assume the routing doesn't work.

So, my question is: What do I need to do for an existing website to start accepting and route incoming web service calls? Is it possible to add this functionality to an existing website, or do I need to start over and create an ASP MVC (or WebApi) application?

Comment: Web Services are deprecated. Use WebApi.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement...

> Just adding a web service to the web site automatically creates an
>   "App_Code" folder to host the C# implementation files

...indicates that you're working with a "website" as opposed to a "web app".

As such, I'm a little surprised that you're getting a 404 for the service file (unless you're trying to reference the class file inside App_Code folder directly in your URL - that won't work).

Although it is possible to hybrid a WebApi project together with a website (e.g. add `System.Web.Routing` to your site and create routes in Global.asax in `Application_Start`), I would be cautious about that approach as it can introduce its own set of challenges.

Assuming your website is ASP.NET 3.5 or greater, the old ASMX web service approach is quite functional. Just make sure to add (or uncomment) the `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` directive before your class (it should be added as a comment automatically when you create an ASMX file). Then, your AJAX URL will be the name of the web service file followed by the name of any functions you have declared with `[WebMethod]` (e.g. `http://MySite/WebService.asmx/MyFunction`).

Do some searches on ASMX and JSON to see about passing and returning data from the service (lots of options).